# Solving $\frac{3^x+2^x}{3^x-2^x}=7$: More than one answer? How to solve for all $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> I am trying to solve this problem (math for fun):
> $$\frac{3^x+2^x}{3^x-2^x}=7$$

Step 1. Let$\:a=3^x\:and\:b=2^x$

Step 2. $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=7$

Step 3. $a+b=7\left(a-b\right)=7a-7b$

Step 4. $6a-8b=0$

Step 5. $6a=8b=3\cdot 2\cdot a=4\cdot 2\cdot b$

Step 6. $3a=4b$

Step 7. $3\cdot 3^x=2\cdot 2\cdot 2^x=3^{x+1}=2^{x+2}$

Step 8. Log both sides

Step 9. $\ln \left(3\right)+x\ln 3=x\ln2+\ln 4$

Step 10. $\ln \left(3\right)-\ln 4=x\:\left(\ln 2-\ln 3\right)$

Step 11. $\frac{\:\left(\ln 3-\ln 4\right)}{\left(\ln 2-\ln 3\right)\:}=x≈0.71$

SOLVED^

Comment: Doesn't $x=1$ yield $5$ instead of $7$?

Comment: Beyond the error focused on by Johnny El Curvas' comment, your work is all correct.  +1 to your query for good work shown.

Comment: Your calculation looks fine to me. Your answer $x \approx 0.71$ looks fine too.

Comment: The answer you got at step 11 looks correct. There is not really a problem at step 3. You are multiplying by $3^{x}-2^{x}$ and you want to avoid that being equal to $0$. It is only equal to $0$ if $x=0$, and you can just observe that $x=0$ is not a solution to the original equation.

Comment: Why do you think there is more than one solution.

Comment: Okay.... through all the edit you probably shouldn't correct to the point that you actually change the question and point of the question.  You should probably edit that you had a question as to why you (incorrectly) thought the answer was $x=1$ but were able to (correctly) derive the answer is $0.71$ and you should make a note it is solved.

Comment: It might be worth noting that $\frac {a+b}{a-b} = 7$ is a *general* equation of which there are infinitely many solutions *for $a$ and $b$*  **OF WHICH** $a=3^x; b=2^x$ is *one* solution for $a,b$. As such it sets up another problem which has just one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you question how do you know how many solutions there are and how to you find them all:  By keeping track of your steps and assuring you never add extraneous solution and that you steps are all one to one reversable so you don't lose or add solutions.

So $\frac {3^x + 2^x}{3^x -2^x} = 7$ gives us the condition that $3^x \ne 2^x$.

Substitute $a =3^x$ and $b=2^x$.  This is just substitution. But we temporarily lose all information we may have about $3^x, 2^x$.  But we don't have to worry we will get the information back.

$\frac {a+b}{a-b} = 7\implies a+b = 7(a-b)$. This adds an extraneous solution where $a = b$ which we know can not happens.  (This is actually some of the information we lost when substitute.  We know $2^x, 3^x > 0$ so $2^x + 3^x > 0$ so $a-b =0$ is not possible... okay lets not worry.  We'll have to keep track $a \ne b$.

$8b = 6a$ just adding to each side.  Completely reversible. This doesn't affect our solutions.

$4b = 3a$ ditto.  This is a restriction.

$4\cdot 2^x = 3\cdot 3^x$

$2^{x+2} = 3^{x+1}$.  We know longer are dealing with $a,b$ so the caviet $a\ne b$ no longer is a concern.

$\ln 2^{x+2} = \ln 3^{x+1}$.  As $\ln$ is one to one this keeps the number of solutions the same.

$(x+2)\ln 2 = (x+1)\ln 3$  Linear shifting doesn't affect anything so

$x(\ln 2 - \ln 3) = (\ln 3 -2\ln 2)=(\ln 3-\ln 4)$.  As $\ln 2-\ln 3$ is a constant and $\ln 2 \ne\ln 3$ we can divide both sides and that doesn't affect the number of solutions.

And $x -\frac {\ln 3 - \ln 4}{\ln 2-\ln 3}$.

Nothing we did lost any solutions and the one thing that added extraneous solution took care of itself.

So we *know* this is the only solution.

BTW $\frac {\ln 3-ln 4}{\ln 3- \ln 2} = \frac {\ln \frac 34}{\ln \frac 32}$ or $\frac {\ln 3 -2\ln 2}{\ln 3 - \ln 2} = 1 -\frac {\ln 2}{\ln 3 - \ln 2}= 1-\frac {\ln 2}{\ln \frac 32}$

If is *helps* (probably doesn't) $\frac {\ln \frac 34}{\ln \frac 32} =\log_{\frac 32} \frac 34=\log_{\frac 32} \frac 32\cdot \frac 12 = 1 - \log_{\frac 32} 2$

Answer (score 3):

$$3^x+2^x=7\cdot3^x-7\cdot2^x$$

$$8\cdot2^x=6\cdot3^x$$

$$\left(\frac32\right)^x=\frac 43$$

and

$$x=\log_{3/2}\frac43.$$

As every steps are equivalent, this is the only solution.